# Creating purchase order with the information from sales order

Tags: acumatica

I'm creating a purchase order based on a sales order via code. 
But how to obtain the document details of sales order and copy it to the new purchase order?

Additional Info:

1. I had created a simple PO in SOOrderEntry BLC. And I also wanna copy the item info(eg:Branch,Inventory ID, Unit Price and so on) in the document details of SO, to the new PO.
2. Below is the my code, and could you help me?

   ```
   namespace PX.Objects.SO {
     public class SOOrderEntry_Extension: PXGraphExtension < SOOrderEntry > {

       #region Event Handlers

       public PXAction < PX.Objects.SO.SOOrder > CreatePO;

       [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
       [PXUIField(DisplayName = "CreatePO")]
       protected void createPO() {

         var graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<POOrderEntry>();
         var order = graph.Document.Insert(new POOrder());
         order.OrderType = "Normal"
         order.OrderDesc = "Some description"; 
         order.VendorID = 101;
         graph.Document.Update(order);
         graph.Actions.PressSave();

       }
       #endregion
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the current code you are implementing so we can help guide you to the best solution? In essence you will be selecting the child records with a PXSelect and then looping through them to create records for your Purchase order.

Comment: @JoshuaVanHoesen Hi, nice to see your reply. and I had add more detail of my question there. Could you help me with this? Thx!